# I get the error when run "composer update" in Magento ver. 2.3.3, PHP 7.3.15

Tags: compiler-errors, composer-php, magento2

I get the error when run "composer update" in Magento ver. 2.3.3, PHP 7.3.15

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin::initModuleDeployment() must be an instance of Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\void, none returned in /home/jesperpu/public_html/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php:69

Stack trace:

## 0 [internal function]: Magento\InventoryComposerInstaller\Plugin->initModuleDeployment(Object(Composer\Script\Event))

## 1 phar:///home/jesperpu/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func(Array, Object(Composer\Script\Event))

## 2 phar:///home/jesperpu/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))

## 3 phar:///home/jesperpu/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php(208): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('pre-update-cmd', true)

## 4 phar:///home/jesperpu/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php(163): Composer\Installer->run()

## 5 phar:///home/jesperpu/composer in /home/jesperpu/public_html/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I use cmd**
composer update --no-plugins --no-dev  phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/type-resolver (locked at 1.0.1) -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/type-resolver[1.0.1].
    - phpdocumentor/type-resolver 1.0.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.

**then I check my PHP:**

PHP -v

PHP 7.3.15 (cli) (built: Feb 21 2020 10:35:52) ( NTS )

**fynaly I run**
whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php

/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer update --no-plugins --no-dev  phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

**ANd it's work**

Answer (score 0):

Try run those commands:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer clearcache
composer update
```

Comment: Do you keep composer.lock ?